# Should I deploy my SPA files to the same "website" as my web service?

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an SPA in angular with a web api backend. If I deploy my SPA files to a separate IIS website from my web service then I have to deal with cross domain requests. But if I put everything in one site, then there's no problem. Is there anything wrong with deploying the two to the same site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not nothing wrong with deploy all in the same server. If you concern is performance remember optimize your js and css files. Also you can use CDN services to serve your static files.